# Command already defined, but is unrecognised

Tags: macros

During a project involving plenty angle brackets, I tried to redefine `\rangle` as `\>` using `\newcommand` to make things a little easier.

However, this called the error "command `\>` already defined". When removing the definition, it does run, although the symbol `\>` appears pink and is listed an unrecognised symbol.

I turned off all packages and there doesn't seem to be any clashing with `\>`. I also defined `\<` as `\langle` in exactly the same way with no such issue occurring.

I'm unsure if this is a bug or if I am missing something subtle.
Using TexStudio.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide more information about how you tried to define the macros `\>` and `\<`. While you're at it, do please state which document class you employ  and which math symbol packages, if any. are loaded by your document.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

TeXStudio is just an editor; the fact that it doesn't highlight a macro doesn't necessarily mean it isn't defined, especially if it's an internal macro (i.e. not intended for direct use in a document).

Now `\<` is undefined as standard, but `\>` is defined as `\mskip \medmuskip`. It's hard to know where this might be used by the kernel or by a package, so changing it would be very unwise. It would be better to define a command such as

```
\newcommand\ang[1]{\langle #1 \rangle}
```

Then you can place an object in angle brackets using `\ang{whatever}`. Depending on your usage case, you might want to use more arguments, for example an inner product might be defined as

```
\newcommand\ip[2]{\langle #1 , #2 \rangle}
```

Finally, you might want to use `\left` and `\right` in your definitions, to allow the bracket sizes to change.

Comment: Thank you, it was just for an inner product, so this should work perfectly

Answer (score 7):

It's impossible for editors to keep track of every command that packages may define (there are thousands of them).

Actually it's a bit surprising that `\>` is ignored, because it is a command defined in the LaTeX kernel with a dual function:

1. an alias to `\:` for back compatibility with plain TeX (and very old LaTeX) documents;
2. a main command inside the `tabbing` environment, which also (re)defines `\<`.

If you don't plan to use `tabbing`, then redefining `\>` might be safe. However, it pops out in some packages:

```
skak xskak blog qsymbols ednotes clrscode3e clrscode zxjatype knitting pax
qqru-shipunov gn-logic14 polytable catoptions bxcjkjatype AlProTex program
sgamevar alphabeta textalpha
```

where it is redefined. I guess you're unlikely to use most of them, but the last two might bite you.

You can do differently:

```
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\foo}{\langle}{\rangle}
```

and then use

```
\foo{x} \foo[\big]{x} ... \foo[\Bigg]{x}
```

where the optional argument sets the size, or `\foo*{x}` for `\left` and `\right` automatic sizing (use sparingly).

Find a better name than `\foo`, of course.

Answer (score 4):

For inner products, you can load `mathtools` and `xparse`and define an `\innerp{a,b}` command this way:

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\innerp}[1]{\langle}{\rangle}{\innpargs{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\innpargs}{ >{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}m }
 {\innpargsaux#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\innpargsaux}{ m m }
 {#1\,,#2}%
```

Using `\innerp*{a,b}` will behave as though there was a pair of `\left\langle` `\right\rangle`. For fine-tuning the size of the delimiters, you can use  an optional argument instead: `\innerp[\big]{a,b}`,  `\innerp[\Big]{a,b}`, &c., which  behaves as though there was a pair of `\bigl\langle` `\bigr\rangle`  or `\Bigl\langle` `Bigr\rangle`, and so on.